# Structured Data Mark-up Effect

Tags: google, google-search, structured-data

How long would it take for the structured data to show in google search snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not guarantee that Rich Snippets will show up for search results from a particular site even if structured data is marked up and can be extracted successfully according to the testing tool.

---

[Quote from Google](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-rich-snippets#howlong):

> **How long does it take for rich snippets to be visible?**
>
> Once you've marked up your site's content, Google will discover it the
>   next time we crawl your site (although it may take some time for rich
>   snippets to appear in search results, if we do choose to display rich
>   snippets for your site)